# How to transform accented characters in html?

Tags: html

I'm using AJAX in my site and Latin 1 characters which is indeed a problem. The solution I found was to convert accented character in html entities but i don't know how.

I'd like to transform ó, for example, in `&oacute;`

I tried to use htmlentities("ó") but it printed `&Atilde;&sup3;`. I don't know what to do anymore

### Better explaining

I'm using ZF and JQuery.
My site uses a form to record some data. To insert this data I use

```
    $data = array(
        'reg_creditorid' => $this->_request->getParam('creditor'),
        'reg_debtorid' => $this->_request->getParam('debtor'),
        'reg_reason' => htmlentities($this->_request->getParam('reason')),
        'reg_value' => str_replace(',', '.', $this->_request->getParam('value')),
        'reg_date' => date('Y-m-d')
    );
    $this->registries->insert($data);
```

When I tried to type **ó** in the *text input* I noticed that when I used getParam, it got `&Atilde;&sup3;` instead of `&oacute;`

I created a test project, with nothing (no ZF, no jQuery, no MVC, nothing). I coded `echo htmlentities('ó');` and it printed `&oacute;`. What could it be, then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the charset you're using for your page to the htmlentities function:

```
htmlentities("ó",ENT_NOQUOTES,'ISO-8859-1')
```

Comment: it still prints &Atilde;&sup3;

Comment: What charset is your page? What charset are you using in your htmlentities function?

Comment: I solved! I just needed to use UTF-8 as the htmlentities' argument

Comment: I'm using ISO-8859-1 in my page but I needed to use UTF-8 as the function's argument in order to record correctly

Answer (score 3):

Pick one character encoding (UTF-8 is a better idea than ISO-8859-1) and stick to it.

Whatever htmlentities is doing, it is treating the data as a different encoding to whatever it is actually using.